# How can I start a process with paramaters without waiting for it to finish and get it's PID in PHP?

Tags: php

So I start a process to open a process and kill the first one so this way it can run in the background, but I don't know how to get the PID of the process that I started the second time. I'm sure that there is another method for running a process in the background and getting it's PID.

Here is the code:

```
function execInBackground($cmd) {
        if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
          pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
        }
    else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
    }
}

execInBackground('start ' . getcwd() . '\\nskip\\run.bat ' . $_SESSION["user"]);
```

Comment: Do you have quotation marks in your path? See this post on [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php#119331)

Answer (score 0):

You need [Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html) for that, php is not like nodejs or synchronous languages, it will work line by line, if you are working with solid php, you need to install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), then symfony, and after that you can run synchronous functions and work with them as you want, kill them with PID or timeout if they didn't reach it.
If you are using Laravel I guess it installs it on init.